# Getting Profile Photo from Microsoft Graph API for Android

Tags: api, graph, picasso

I have recently started working on an android project that uses Microsft authentication and graph API. By following this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-android
I am able to authenticate and get some data from graph API. Now I want to load the profile photo of Microsoft account in the app. For this purpose, I used ProfilePhoto object with a call back as follows:

```
    graphClient
            .me()
            .photo()
            .buildRequest()
            .get(new ICallback<ProfilePhoto>() {

                @Override
                public void success(ProfilePhoto profilePhoto) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Found " + profilePhoto.getRawObject().toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(ClientException ex) {
                    displayError(ex);
                }
            });
```

Here profilePhoto.getRawObject() returns a json file like:

```
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('hanzla_hawk%40outlook.com')/photo/$entity","@odata.mediaContentType":"image/png","@odata.mediaEtag":"W/\"8050a078da935403cf67163f23f1baace5c7abf3ff784452cb08c38660308a83\"","id":"default","height":256,"width":256}
```

With this Json, how can I load the image into an image view? I have previous experience with Picasso and other fake apis. But right now I just dont know what should I pass in the Picasso to load image from this json.

Answer (score 1):

I have just make a call to get a profile photo to show on an Android app using Jetpack Compose views in Kotlin. To achieve it I have followed your question and this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/android

You almost got it. Just add `.content()` call between `.me().photo()` and `.buildRequest()`.

This is my code on my project to get the photo content:

```
// GET /me/photo/$value (logged in user)
fun getUserPhoto(
    onGotPhoto: (ImageBitmap) -> Unit,
    onGotError: (Exception) -> Unit
) {
    mClient!!.me().photo().content().buildRequest()
        .async
        .thenAccept { inputStream ->
            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream).asImageBitmap()
            onGotPhoto.invoke(bitmap)
        }
        .exceptionally { processError(it, onGotError) }
}
```